# Does circular references cause memory leaks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, memory-leaks, cross-browser

I've read many claims stating that circular references will cause memory leaks:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/02/javascript_memo.html
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closuresleak/index3.shtml

So I tested this script on Chrome / FF4 / IE9 / Opera / Safari:

```
<script>
var a, b, list = [];

for(var x=0;x<1000000;x+=2){
    a = list[x] = document.createElement("div");
    b = list[x + 1] = document.createElement("div");
    a.hook = b;
    b.hook = a;
}
</script>
```

Task manager shows that the script consumes ~0.2 GB of memory.

Then I refreshed the page 10 times. If the script does cause memory leaks, after 10 refreshes I should be seeing ~2 GB of memory consumed, yet task manager shows otherwise.

In **which browsers** do circular references cause memory leaks in JavaScript?

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/

Answer (score 4):

Memory leaks were mainly an issue in older IEs with circular references and reference counting garbage collection that never quite reclaimed everything (never a reference count of 0 in circular references).

I think memory leaks in IE have been fixed since IE8.

[Microsoft have a in depth article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: so in other words, no matter how we try, javascript memory leaks is not possible anymore?

Comment: @Pacerier Well IE7 and IE6 are still pretty common.

Comment: ok let me rephrase my question. so can we say that memory leaks is 100% not possible anymore in modern browsers?

Comment: @Pacerier I'm not 100% sure. You can always crack open the source to your favourite open source browser and see if any memory is not freed in any circumstance.

Comment: @Pacerier, Microsoft is sick and tired of IE6; they realize it is pretty horrible by modern standards, and want to get people to move to nicer, newer browsers. They don't want to be known for horrible browsers, just because people haven't upgraded recently...

Comment: You can never say you're 100% free from memory leaks. Software will always have unforeseen bugs.